# iOS search bar animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to add a animation in a search bar when the user taps on it (just like the animation in whatsApp or telegram [only in iOS])

[here is the animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih0En.gif)

I used Hero widget to do so but the widget is not working, I don't know why. Here is my code for it

```
Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
  //some widgets above the search bar
  Hero(
    tag: 'search',
    child: Container(
      height: 38,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        cursorColor: Colors.blue,

        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          hintText: "Search here",
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  //some more widgets here inside the column
])
```

This is part of code for 1st page and the other page is just the search bar.
This is the other page which is almost the same

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Hero(
        tag: 'search',
        child: Container(
          height: 38,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
          ),
          child: TextField(
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              hintText: "Search here",
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Also is there any other way to do it?

EDIT: It's now working fine with Hero widget but it does not show that exact behaviour as in the above gif. How should I do that, if someone has any other method to achieve that, can also answer.

Comment: Please refers to: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html , that widget is exactly what you need to achieve that animation.

Comment: Thanks for answering but i want the widgets above the search field to move upwards and disappear just like in telegram or whatsapp (only iOS devices) and ```AnimatedCrossFade``` does not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hero is used when moving between different pages here(in the above animation) we are not navigating to any other page, so, remove the `Hero` widget

This can be done with `Transform.translate` in combination with `Opacity()` widget in Flutter.

Wrap the respective widget with `Transform.translate` create a Tween Animation and change its height with the help of `Offset(dx, dy)` (in this case dx will be 0 and dy will be the changing height), negative dy value will move the widget upwards. Also wrap it with `Opacity()` and change the value with the changing value of height.

```
Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
  Transform.translate(
    offset: Offset(0, animatedHeightFromTweenAnimation)
    child: Opacity(
      opacity: animatedHeightFromTweenAnimation/maxHeightValue;
      child: anyWidget()
    )
  )
  Container(
    height: 38,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
    ),
    child: TextField(
      cursorColor: Colors.blue,

      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        hintText: "Search here",
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
    ),
  ),//container
  RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => controller.forward(), //here controller is animation controller
          //the above line will start the animation
    child: Text("press it"),
  ),
  //some more widgets here inside the column
])
```